# PowerShell Find and Replace a string by position

Tags: powershell, file, recursion, replace, find

I have a directory full of text files.  They all have differing extensions but they are all just text files.
Within each text file is a "$" in position 7 on multiple lines within the file.
The lines that have a "$" in position 7 are mucking up our procedures and cannot be ingested correctly into the software.
The lines that have a "$" anywhere BUT position 7 is fine.  There are "$" used throughout the files so I can ONLY change the "$" found in position 7.
I need to change all the lines that have a "$" in position 7 so I have to read the whole file, line by line, looking for the "$" in position 7 and replacing it with an "*".

I've been working with the script below and having issues just trying to replace any "$".  I think I need to put an escape in there somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
-NJ

```
$exclude = @("*log*", "*bak*")
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\temp", "c:\temp" -Recurse -exclude $exclude 
 
foreach ($file in $files){
 
$find = "$"
$replace = "*"
$content = Get-Content $($file.FullName) -Raw
#write replaced content back to the file
$content -replace $find,$replace | Out-File $($file.FullName) 
}
```

Comment: [1] load the file with `Get-Content` [but not with `-Raw`] ///// [2] iterate thru the lines ///// [3] test the 7th char with something like `Line[6] -eq '$'` ///// [4] if found, replace it with something like `$Line[6] = '*'` ///// [5] send the lines out to a `$CurFileCollection` until you run out of lines ///// [6] write that collection to the target file [or, safer, to a new file in  a different dir] ///// [7] go to the next file

Comment: You can do `$content -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{6})\$',$replace`